# Can I make my graphql query multipurpose?

Tags: graphql

I would like to query products by different filters and criteria so I have written multiple queries for my frontend for each case (shown below). Is there a way I can write and use one "multipurpose" query instead of these?

```js
const GET_PRODUCTS = gql`
  query {
    products {
      ...productFragment
    }
  }
  ${PRODUCT_FRAGMENT}
`

const GET_PRODUCTS_BY_PRICE = gql`
  query($sortFilter: String) {
    products(sort: $sortFilter) {
      # (sort: "price:asc") or (sort: "price:desc")
      ...productFragment
    }
  }
  ${PRODUCT_FRAGMENT}
`

const GET_PRODUCTS_BY_CATEGORY = gql`
  query($categoryId: String) {
    products(where: { categories: { id: $categoryId } }) {
      ...productFragment
    }
  }
  ${PRODUCT_FRAGMENT}
`

const GET_PRODUCTS_BY_CATEGORY_AND_PRICE = gql`
  query($sortFilter: String, $categoryId: String) {
    products(sort: $sortFilter, where: { categories: { id: $categoryId } }) {
      ...productFragment
    }
  }
  ${PRODUCT_FRAGMENT}
`
```

Looks like I can write a helper fn like this then:

```js
function getRequiredProductsQuery({ sortFilter, categoryId }) {
  if (sortFilter && categoryId) {
    return { key: 'PRODUCTS_BY_CATEGORY_AND_PRICE', query: GET_PRODUCTS_BY_CATEGORY_AND_PRICE }
  }
  if (sortFilter) {
    return { key: 'PRODUCTS_BY_PRICE', query: GET_PRODUCTS_BY_PRICE }
  }
  if (categoryId) {
    return { key: 'PRODUCTS_BY_CATEGORY', query: GET_PRODUCTS_BY_CATEGORY }
  }
  return { key: 'PRODUCTS', query: GET_PRODUCTS }
}
```

Is it really all necessary?

Comment: just `sortFilter` and `where` params?

Answer (score 0):

ok, I figured that I can provide default params like $categoryId: String = "id:asc"